# Play video in setFrame method

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have to play my video in view given CGRectMake. But always it's playing full screen only. I'm using MPMoviewPlayerViewController.

```
NSString *path;

    path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"solar" ofType:@"mp4"];

 mpviewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
mpviewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300);

    [self.view addSubview:mpviewController.view];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpviewController];
```

Comment: Why are you both presenting `mpviewController` and add its `view` as a subview? That makes no sense.

Comment: I have background image. I need to play video in center of the imageview

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: You should really read the documentation of `MPMoviePlayerViewController` very carefully. Line 1: `The MPMoviePlayerViewController class implements a simple view controller for displaying full-screen movies.`

Answer (score 0):

you have to set MpMoiveScalling mode to aspect fit so just set this line of code and you done.

```
  MPMoviePlayerController *obj; [obj   
    setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeFill];
```

It worked for me.

Comment: class method +setScalingMode not found

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line,

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpviewController];
```

Working Sample code,

```
 - (IBAction)playVideoAction:(id)sender
{
    float width = 200;
    float height = 300;
    MPMoviePlayerViewController* theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:moviePathURL];
    theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - width)/2, (self.view.frame.size.height - height)/2, width, height);
    [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i apply this code in my application.

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300);
```

Thanks.